# Window's Explorer not displaying actual filepath

Tags: windows-explorer, robocopy

My company uses **Robocopy** to backup our systems, and in the backup folders, the shown names are not correct.

What is expected, is "This PC > Drive > backup > Store > SYSTEMNAME". What is shown in the address bar in Window's Explorer, though, is along the lines of "This PC > Drive > backup > Store > Users".

When clicked on, it then displays the real file path, "Drive:/backup/store/SYSTEMNAME". It only does this for certain systems, despite the Robocopy commands being identical, same for the system names.

Comment: I think you will need to show the Robocopy commands you are using for these backup jobs. It'd be nice to understand where the scripts are executed from as well—on each machine or from a server?

Comment: What is "clicked on"? Are you using symlinks, hardlinks or junctions?

Comment: @McDonald's They are executed from a sever. An example of one of ours would be along the lines of `robocopy /R:0 /W:0 /NP /LOG+:\logs\COMP_NAME.log /mir "\\COMP_NAME\c$\users" "D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME" /XD "temporary internet files" "appdata" "history" "cookies" "application data" "channels" "temp" "local settings" "start menu" /XF "*.mp3"`

Comment: @El8tedN8te What I meant is, when the address bar in Window's Explorer is clicked on, the full path is not the same as what the simplified path it displays is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Robocopy Expected Destination Not Correct Issue

When you use [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) you will want to be sure the last specified folder in the source and destination paths are those of the level you want it to copy to and from starting point wise—I always think of it like a root to root copy perspective in this respect.

Using this below syntax **Script Example** should resolve this problem you describe moving forward.

### Script Example

```
robocopy /R:0 /W:0 /NP /LOG+:\logs\COMP_NAME.log /mir "\\COMP_NAME\c$\users" "D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME\Users" /XD "temporary internet files" "appdata" "history" "cookies" "application data" "channels" "temp" "local settings" "start menu" /XF "*.mp3"
```

> **Essentially to keep it short to show you what to change. . .**
>
> Where you were using:
>
> ```
> robocopy /mir "\\COMP_NAME\c$\users" "D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME"
> ```
>
> Use this instead:
>
> ```
> robocopy /mir "\\COMP_NAME\c$\users" "D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME\Users"
> ```

---

### Further Resources

- [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've applied this to one of our system's backups. I'll know tomorrow how if it worked out for me.

Comment: I feel you got it right. I think the person who first wrote the script wanted the output to just be
`D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME` 
as opposed to
`D:\backup\STORE\COMP_NAME\Users`
but if I understand correctly, not including the "\Users" is what's causing this visual error.

Comment: The backup ran, but it did not change the simplified name of the folder. I think, though, that it's because the folder already existed, and I merely placed a another folder inside it. I updated the path so it's more like `D:\backup\OTHER_STORE\COMP_NAME\Users` so I will know tomorrow if that worked.